# push updates to gcloud containers/pods

Tags: node.js, docker, kubernetes, gcloud

Went through to [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/docs/tutorials/hello-node) without any issues but I'm confused on the best way to push updates to the application.  The tutorial mentions a bit about `kubectl rolling-update` but not really following that. Any feedback on exact steps to use after deploying the app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the [kubectl rolling update](http://kubernetes.io/v1.1/docs/user-guide/kubectl/kubectl_rolling-update.html) command.

For a bit of background, imagine that you have an application that is running in 10 pods. Now you have a new version of your application. You don't want to stop the current version and then start the new version, because you will have a period of time where you aren't serving any user traffic. And if there is an issue with the new version, that period of time may be quite long as you push the new version, detect an issue, remove the new version, and restart the old version. A rolling update will replace your pods one at a time with a new pod running the updated version of your application. This allows you to gradually shift incoming requests to the new version without any downtime. It also allows you to catch issues with your new version while it serving a fraction of incoming requests.